# What software can turn HDL into a Schematic?

Tags: programming, hardware, virtual-machine, electronics, binary-data

HDL is used to create Hardware Descriptions as the name suggests. However I am wondering what is the next step in creating hardware from HDL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't go from HDL to schematics. The next step is synthesis. Your FPGA vendor's tools do that. Or Synopsys (or similar expensive tools) for ASICs.

Comment: So I guess there is no way for a student in Community College to turn HDL into hardware?

Comment: @Jason Ivey: Yes you can. Look into FPGAs. There are some low-cost boards for them.